# how to create a treeview structure in React JS and add a child node at any position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to create a tree view in react js as i mentioned above i am using this library but can't add a child node in that please help me out
https://ant.design/components/tree/

I have to create like this
https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/demos/Nav/TreeView/Nodes/Adding/react

code link
https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-zhukovsky-9v77i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! could you share your code please?

Comment: Provide more info about the issue you are facing, say like sample code/codepen  link to get it answered. Go through the Documentation of antd once again

Comment: Code link: - https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-zhukovsky-9v77i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.